# How do I write this line of code without C# thinking it is an escape sequence?

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("|/                       \|");
```

When I try to write this in the console, it thinks the slashes are escape sequences (that are unknown), and returns the error:

```
Compilation error (line 22, col 48): Unrecognized escape sequence
```

Comment: Since an escape character means "interpret the following character specially", what do you think an escape character followed by an escape character means?

Answer (score 3):

Either use raw strings:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"|/                       \|");
```

Or escape your slash:

```
Console.WriteLine("|/                       \\|");
```